# 'With' in pre python 2.5

Tags: python, legacy, with-statement

Is there a means of converting a python 'with' statement into a format that can be used in previous versions of python. 4 month's work hinging on this question. with  are there to be more efficient than their previous counterparts, but efficiency is not important here.

Answer (score 3):

Use `try:` `except:` `finally:`

The `finally:` clause can handle the close.

See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/ for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

As S.Lott has stated, try and finally should handle the work of the with clause. I'm not sure that `with` actually catches any errors, so given that assumption:

```
with open(file_name,mode) as name: # Or whatever expression
    do_this()
```

can be replaced with

```
try:
   name = open(filename,mode)   # Or whatever expression
   do_this()
finally:
   name.close()
```

Comment: Should that not be `finally: if name: name.close()` ?

Comment: No, the assignment to name should happen outside the try block.